# What's Wrong with this DHT22?

Tags: c++, temperature-sensor

I made a circuit that takes humidity and temperature from DHT22 sensor and displays it on Lcd Screen. Simple enough but i get this error "Failed to read from DHT". That happens because i have this code

```
 if (isnan(t) || isnan(h)) {
  delay(100);
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
  } else {
    delay(100);
    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(h);
    Serial.print(" %\t");
    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(t);
    Serial.println(" *C");
    //lcd.print("Temp: ") ;
    //lcd.print(t);
    //lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    //lcd.print("Hum: ") ;
    //lcd.print(h);
  }
```

So the values are **NaN** . But 1 minute before it worked fine, and now again it doesnt. Everything is soldered the right way and nothing is false. Lcd is wired ok and it works but i dont get values from DHT22.

Here are some pics to help you out.
[image: Overview]
[image: Wiring]
[image: Wiring]

In the third Image we see its working. And now its not! 
is the DHT sensor broken?

```
  #include "DHT.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>`

#define DHTPIN 2     
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("DHT22 test!");
  lcd.begin(16, 2)
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {

  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();


  if (isnan(t) || isnan(h)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
  } else {

    lcd.print("Hum: ");
    lcd.print(h);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

    lcd.print("Temp: ");
    lcd.print(t);

  }
}
```

Thats my code by the way

Comment: What lib are you using? Can you post your setup code also?

Comment: `#include "DHT.h"`
`#include <LiquidCrystal.h>`

#define DHTPIN 2     
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("DHT22 test!");
  lcd.begin(16, 2)
  dht.begin();
}
 
void loop() {

  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
 
  
  if (isnan(t) || isnan(h)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
  } else {

    lcd.print("Hum: ");
    lcd.print(h);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    
    lcd.print("Temp: ");
    lcd.print(t);
    
  }
}`

Comment: Please amend your question to post the code. Putting it in a comment is pretty-much unreadable.

Comment: @NickGammon  done

Comment: I can't see a resistor in your photo (maybe it is hidden). There should be a 10 k pull-up from pin 2 to 5V (that is, between pin 2 and pin 1). Do you have that?

Comment: @NickGammon no and I guess I don't need that.  Lcd works fine

Comment: I always use Adafruit_Sensor and DHT - have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to put a delay in between your read requests. Currently you're reading way too fast, every few milliseconds you're hitting the DHT. Max interval should be every two seconds or so.
2. Add a 10k resistor between pin 1 and 2 of the DHT.

I'd bet adding a delay, or using the simpleTimer library to control how frequently you read from the DHT will clear this up.

Comment: Where should I put resistor

Comment: Solder between pin 1 and 2 on DHT. Google image it. It's a very common question.